# Wordpress does not use static page as landing page

Tags: wordpress, static

On my wordpress site I have only pages, no blog posts.
I want 'News' to be the landing page when people come to my site. I went to the reading settings, set 'News' as static front page.
Still, every time I leave the site and come back to it, it opens on the last visited page (not only by me, if you go there now and leave with the 'contact' page open, I'll see the 'contact' page when I visit the site after you).
When I go to the reading settings after leaving the site on a specific page, that page is showing as the static front page. So it does not seem to remember my preferences.

Googling does not seem to give me a solution so I'm very dissappointed in it today. ;)

Comment: can you provide site url?

Comment: there are a lot of possibilities for this happening but it is not wordpress behaviour by default. Change your theme and disable all plugins. Re-activate one by one to see where the fault is.

Comment: Forgot to mention, did change the theme already. That didn't help. Will try the plugins. Edit: It's the translation plugin I use. Too bad, I really need that one. :) Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: There is some cache plugin that is causing this. Clear all caches and disable cache plugings.